Why does Lipschitz continuity imply Holder continuity?
I was wondering why would a Lipschitz continous function also be Holder continous? Shouldn't the implication be backwards, because Lipschitz continuity is a special case of Holder continuity where the exponent is euqal to $1$?

As you wrote, it is a speicial case of Hölder ...

Yes but that's precisely my question, if a function is Holder continuous it should imply that it's also Lipschitz continuous, but the implication is rather that since a function is Lipschitz continuous it is also Holder, which doesn't make sense because if the inequality works for alpha=1 why should it hold for all other positive alpha?
